# How to get older version of expo client app for ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

please can anyone help me with a link  where i can download old expo client IPA file that can work with expo SDK 37(I already have many android users using the build made with SDK 37), the current one in app store(expo go) can only work with SDK 38,39,40....,   am so in need of it that i have been searching for it for the past two days and don't know what else to do than to ask this question, thanks.

Comment: This is off topic for StackOverflow, since it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the links for the older Expo version here https://expo.io/--/api/v2/versions

Comment: Thanks so much, this is really helpful.

Comment: Hi Rezden , i was able to download a compressed file that seems to be a lower version of expo client for ios, but cant seem to find a way to install it on an iphone, cant even get an ipa, please any ideas on how to get the ipa or install it on an ios device ,link to the compressed file i downloaded https://dpq5q02fu5f55.cloudfront.net/Exponent-2.15.4.tar.gz     ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade the Expo Go app, you need to download the tar.gz then install it using:

`xcrun simctl install booted [path to untarred directory]`

More can be read here: https://forums.expo.dev/t/downgrade-expo-client-app-in-ios-simulator/10634/2